# Spring Jpa Multiple output paramters in stored procedure - Exception "No property found for type"

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I call oracle stored procedure using spring-data-jpa:2.1.9.RELEASE (Spring boot 2.1.6 RELEASE)

**Procedure:**

```
procedure proc(data in varchar2, res1 out number, res2 out number)
begin
  insert into table (id, data) values (abc.hibernate_sequence.nextval, data)
  returning id into res1;
  res2 := id*5;
end proc;
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table", schema = "abc')
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "testName", procedureName = "proc", parameters = {
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "data", type = String.class),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "res1", type = Long.class),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "res2", type = Long.class) 
})
public class testEntity { ... }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long> {

  @Transactional
  @Procedure(name = "testName")
  Map<String, Long> procedure(@Param("data") String data);
}
```

When I start application:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Map TestEntityRepository.procedure(java.lang.String)! 
No property procedure found for type TestEntity
```

If i use stored procedure with only 1 output parameter everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one out parameter can be fetched with `@Procedure` annotation prior to **spring-data-jpa:2.2.0.RELEASE**.

If you can't change the dependency version then you will have to make it work with following code :

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = this.em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("testName");
query.setParameter("data", "data_value");
query.execute();
Long sum = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue("res1");
Long sum = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue("res2");
```